# Installation of ibm mq chart using helm in Gcp,created a error during pod creation "Creashloopbackoff"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, ibm-mq, kubernetes-helm

[image: Take a look of image]

IBM Mq Helm chart installation failed to create Pod showing "Crashloop Backoff error". Pod error Message:
mkdir /mnt/mqm/data: permission denied. Infrastructure: Google Cloud Platform ,Kubectl version: Client Version: v1.18.6
Server Version: v1.16.13-gke.1.
helm chart :helm repo add ibm-charts https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/stable/

Comment: Try setting `security.initVolumeAsRoot` to `true` in Helm values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue with permissions on the mounted volume. You can try resolving this   by adding the following additional parameter when you do the helm install:
On CLI: `--set security.initVolumeAsRoot=true`
On UI: Select the check-box for initVolumeAsRoot

This will allow init-container to run as root and setup the filesystem, which can then be used by the queue manager.