# IBM-MQ helm chart kubernetes can't see resource limits

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, ibm-mq, helmfile

I'm trying to deploy IBM-MQ to Kubernetes (Rancher) using helmfile. I was getting the same error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63339512/installation-of-ibm-mq-chart-using-helm-in-gcp-created-a-error-during-pod-creati).

It wasn't working with storage class "longhorn", but was working with storage class "local-path". I added `security: initVolumeAsRoot: true` to my helmfile, now it looks like this:

```
....
  - name: ibm-mq
    ...
    chart: ibm-stable-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev
    values:
      - license: accept
        security:
          initVolumeAsRoot: true
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 800m
            memory: 800Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 512Mi
        image:
          tag: latest
        dataPVC:
          storageClassName: "longhorn"
          size: 500Mi
       ...
```

But in the Lens in the Stateful Sets I can see that it can't create a pod because of the error `create Pod ibm-mq-0 in StatefulSet ibm-mq failed error: pods "ibm-mq-0" is forbidden: failed quota: default: must specify limits.cpu,limits.memory`.

But the same helmfile without `security` worked fine, it didn't get an error because of limits, but got an error because there were problems with `longhorn` (as in the question I linked). If I change it to `local-path` (without `security`) it works fine, but the problem is that with `local-path` I need to delete manually volume after every restart, which is not what I want (for example, database works on longhorn without deleting volume after every restart). What's might be the problem here? I'm running it using `helmfile -n namespace apply`

UPD: I tried to place all the values in the order they're presented [here](https://github.com/IBM/charts/blob/master/stable/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev/values.yaml#L114), but it didn't work. I'm using helm 3, helmfile v.0.141.0, kubectl 1.22.2